# iteration algoritm on Python (permutations with required position)

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples, permutation

I have follow input data:

```
input_data = [
    ('obj1', 0),
    ('obj2', 0),
    ('obj3', 0),
    ('obj22', 0),
    ('obj4', 1),
    ('obj5', 1),
    ('obj6', 1),
    ('obj7', 2),
    ('obj8', 2),
    ('obj9', 3),
    ('obj10', 3),
]
```

I need to write an algorithm that will make permutations
by 2 but except items where position (second element in tuple)
for a left item will >= position of a right item or less than 1.

Example output:

```
expected = [
    [('obj1', 0), ('obj4', 1)],
    [('obj1', 0), ('obj5', 1)],
    [('obj1', 0), ('obj6', 1)],

    [('obj2', 0), ('obj4', 1)],
    [('obj2', 0), ('obj5', 1)],
    [('obj2', 0), ('obj6', 1)],

    [('obj3', 0), ('obj4', 1)],
    [('obj3', 0), ('obj5', 1)],
    [('obj3', 0), ('obj6', 1)],

    [('obj22', 0), ('obj4', 1)],
    [('obj22', 0), ('obj5', 1)],
    [('obj22', 0), ('obj5', 1)],

    [('obj4', 1), ('obj7', 2)],
    [('obj4', 1), ('obj8', 2)],

    [('obj5', 1), ('obj7', 2)],
    [('obj5', 1), ('obj8', 2)],

    [('obj6', 1), ('obj7', 2)],
    [('obj6', 1), ('obj8', 2)],

    [('obj7', 2), ('obj9', 3)],
    [('obj7', 2), ('obj10', 3)],

    [('obj8', 2), ('obj9', 3)],
    [('obj8', 2), ('obj10', 3)],
]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question right, below would be your answer:

```py
from itertools import permutations

input_data = [
    ('obj1', 0),
    ('obj2', 0),
    ('obj3', 0),
    ('obj22', 0),
    ('obj4', 1),
    ('obj5', 1),
    ('obj6', 1),
    ('obj7', 2),
    ('obj8', 2),
    ('obj9', 3),
    ('obj10', 3),
]

perm = permutations(input_data, 2)

expected = []
for p in perm:
    if p[0][1] < p[1][1]:
        expected.append([p[0], p[1]])
```

Result:

```sh
expected = [
[('obj1', 0), ('obj4', 1)]
[('obj1', 0), ('obj5', 1)]
[('obj1', 0), ('obj6', 1)]
[('obj1', 0), ('obj7', 2)]
[('obj1', 0), ('obj8', 2)]
[('obj1', 0), ('obj9', 3)]
[('obj1', 0), ('obj10', 3)]
[('obj2', 0), ('obj4', 1)]
[('obj2', 0), ('obj5', 1)]
[('obj2', 0), ('obj6', 1)]
[('obj2', 0), ('obj7', 2)]
[('obj2', 0), ('obj8', 2)]
[('obj2', 0), ('obj9', 3)]
[('obj2', 0), ('obj10', 3)]
[('obj3', 0), ('obj4', 1)]
[('obj3', 0), ('obj5', 1)]
[('obj3', 0), ('obj6', 1)]
[('obj3', 0), ('obj7', 2)]
[('obj3', 0), ('obj8', 2)]
[('obj3', 0), ('obj9', 3)]
[('obj3', 0), ('obj10', 3)]
[('obj22', 0), ('obj4', 1)]
[('obj22', 0), ('obj5', 1)]
[('obj22', 0), ('obj6', 1)]
[('obj22', 0), ('obj7', 2)]
[('obj22', 0), ('obj8', 2)]
[('obj22', 0), ('obj9', 3)]
[('obj22', 0), ('obj10', 3)]
[('obj4', 1), ('obj7', 2)]
[('obj4', 1), ('obj8', 2)]
[('obj4', 1), ('obj9', 3)]
[('obj4', 1), ('obj10', 3)]
[('obj5', 1), ('obj7', 2)]
[('obj5', 1), ('obj8', 2)]
[('obj5', 1), ('obj9', 3)]
[('obj5', 1), ('obj10', 3)]
[('obj6', 1), ('obj7', 2)]
[('obj6', 1), ('obj8', 2)]
[('obj6', 1), ('obj9', 3)]
[('obj6', 1), ('obj10', 3)]
[('obj7', 2), ('obj9', 3)]
[('obj7', 2), ('obj10', 3)]
[('obj8', 2), ('obj9', 3)]
[('obj8', 2), ('obj10', 3)]
]
```